# Parser error when trying to access the ASP.NET password recovery page?

Tags: asp.net, parsing, compilation

When I try to access my ASP.NET password recovery page, I get the following error:

> Description: An error occurred during
>   the parsing of a resource required to
>   service this request. Please review
>   the following specific parse error
>   details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load
>   type 'RugbyClubWebApplication.ForgotPassword'.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SubMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ForgotPassword.aspx.cs" Inherits="RugbyClubWebApplication.ForgotPassword" Title="Untitled Page" %>
Line 2:  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
Line 3:  </asp:Content>
```

Source File: /Rugby/ForgotPassword.aspx    Line: 1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to fix this by simply cleaning and rebuilding the entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes happen when file or project names change and class or namespaces aren't updated. Is the name of the class defined in ForgotPassword.aspx.cs actually `ForgotPassword`, and is it in the namespace `RugbyClubWebApplication`?

i.e. you should have the following in your class file:

```
namespace RugbyClubWebApplication
{
    public class ForgotPassword
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, if you're using Visual Studio, is the Default Namespace of the project which contains this class correct? This is found in the Properties page of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this to be an ASP.NET 2.0 Website project and that the class name and file names are correct, you should try replacing the `CodeBehind` attribute of the `@Page` directive with the `CodeFile` attribute, instead. In .NET 2.0 and above, the `CodeBehind` attribute exists only for backward compatibility and you should be using the `CodeFile` attribute along with the `Inherits` to specify a code behind file along with class name.